# What is the right size for vector drawable icons?

Tags: android, svg, icons, android-vectordrawable

What is the correct size to choose for Vector Drawable icons e.g. when importing them from SVG?

There is a lot of information about standard icon dimensions for raster icons, for example [this site](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/). However, I'm a little bit struggling to get icons imported from SVG appear normally, I'm basically determining them by trial and error.

Particularly interested in launcher and notification icon sizes. I've currently settled on 192x192 for launcher icons and 48x48 for notification icons.

Using a smaller size for launcher icons results in a blurred icon on my KitKat tablet and using a larger size looks bad as well.

But the notification icon still appears larger than in other apps so it should probably be something like 32x32.

Comment: I usually use [these](https://design.google.com/icons/) icons in my projects. They offer different sizes to download, from 18x18 do 48x48

Comment: @Vucko I use them too, good stuff. But now I drew my own SVG icon and can't make it look right (not a designer or SVG pro by any means).

Comment: Oh how I get you. I cant draw shit. So I'm making my sister learn illustrator and similar shit in order for me to not have to do it :D Why don't you then use 24x24? That's the default when you download from here I guess..

Comment: I switched to 24x24 for notifications, seem to be ok on both tablets and phones, I guess I'll stick to it. Launcher icons look pretty bad with this size though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose what is the best, what it depends on is the version of Android, the default is 24x24 dp

Comment: I don't get it why a vector image have a size? isn't that scalable to any size?